# How to create a column based on other columns in a vectorized/fast fashion?

Tags: r, dplyr, tidyverse, case-when, rowwise

I need to create one column which is base on other two columns. The thing is I don't want to use `rowwise` because it makes it too slow when used on large data, when I don't use `rowwise` it does not work.

```
library(tidyverse)

df <- tibble(
 param1 = c(NA, "---", "< 2,8", "5", "6", "7", "-"),
 param2 = c("---", "4", "5.5", "6", NA, "< 10,8", "6")
)

# A tibble: 7 x 2
  param1 param2
  <chr>  <chr> 
1 NA     ---   
2 ---    4     
3 < 2,8  5.5   
4 5      6     
5 6      NA    
6 7      < 10,8
7 -      6
```

desired_output:

```
# A tibble: 7 x 3
# Rowwise: 
  param1 param2 param3
  <chr>  <chr>  <chr> 
1 NA     ---    NA    
2 ---    4      NA    
3 < 2,8  5.5    6.9   
4 5      6      11    
5 6      NA     NA    
6 7      < 10,8 12.4  
7 -      6      NA
```

This is what I tried so far, which produces the correct output, but as I said, it is slow because of `rowwise`, is there another fast vectorized option?. I'm open to other approaches. Thanks.

```
somefunction <- function(value) {
  
  parse_number(str_remove(str_replace(value, ",", "."), "<")) * (as.numeric(!str_detect(value, "<")) + 1)/2
  
}

df %>% 
  rowwise() %>% 
  mutate(
    param3 = case_when(
      is.na(param1) || is.na(param2) || str_detect(param1, "^-") || str_detect(param2, "^-") ~ NA_character_,
      TRUE ~ as.character(somefunction(param1) + somefunction(param2))
    )
  )
```

Comment: how you get 6.9 in row 3 in `param3` column?

Comment: yes, when the number has "<" at the beginning, it is divided in two.

Answer (score 1):

i'm sure there could be many other approaches but this could be of help:

```
output <- data.frame(param1,param2,param3 = somefunction(df$param1) + somefunction(df$param2))
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is tidyverse solution alone:

**Explanation**

- In essence it is a sum of two columns `mutate(param3 = param1 + param2)`
- First ad `id` to handle the change of wide to long format and back
- Make long format `pivot_longer` `tidyr`
- Do some manipulation: commented out in the code
- Back to wide format `pivot_wider`
- sum `param1` and `param2`

```
library(tidyverse)
df %>% 
  mutate(id = row_number()) %>% 
  pivot_longer(
    cols = starts_with("param"),
    names_to = "param"
  ) %>% 
  mutate(value = gsub("\\,", ".", value)) %>% # , to .
  mutate(first = str_extract(value, "^[^\\s]+"),
         rest = str_extract(value, "\\s.+")) %>%  # isolte <
  mutate(value = as.numeric(gsub("[^[:digit:].]", "",  value))) %>%  # now column is numeric
  mutate(value = ifelse(first =="<", value/2, value)) %>% # solving this < then divide by two problem
  select(-first, -rest) %>% 
  pivot_wider(names_from = "param", values_from = "value") %>%  # back to wide format
  mutate(param3 = param1 + param2) %>% 
  select(-id)
```

Output:

```
# A tibble: 7 x 3
  param1 param2 param3
   <dbl>  <dbl>  <dbl>
1   NA     NA     NA  
2   NA      4     NA  
3    1.4    5.5    6.9
4    5      6     11  
5    6     NA     NA  
6    7      5.4   12.4
7   NA      6     NA
```

Comment: It is too much code for something that simple, so far the less time-consuming is Alvaro Morales's solution.

Comment: You are right one line is shorter. Anyway this was my solution!

Answer (score 0):

I think this is hard to debug because you are trying to do to many things at one time.  You're trying to handle NA's, text to numeric conversions, and back to character.  You can use the profile package to see what part of the code is actually slow, but otherwise it's hard to tell.

I would recommend defining the NA's in a new column how you want them, then you can use ifelse(), which is vectorized, to generate the numeric transformation.  Once you have the numbers, then convert them to character, which is vectorized.

Answer (score 0):

It works with this, It is similar to `user15482151` solution, thanks.

```
df %>% 
  mutate(
    param3 = as.character(somefunction(param1) + somefunction(param2))
    )
```

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
otherfunction <- function(x){
    a <- parse_number(str_extract(x,"\\d+,{0,1}\\d*"), locale = locale(decimal_mark = ",")) *if_else(grepl("<",x),1/2,1)
    if_else(grepl("^-",x) | is.na(x),NA_real_,a)
    }

df %>% mutate(param3 = as.character(otherfunction(param1)+otherfunction(param2)))
```